# Dynamic JFreechart area chart with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a dynamic jfreechart area chart and I want to add an horizontal scroll bar which show me old values displayed in my chart because my chart is showin only the values of the last 10 seconds of my timer. 
How to do this?  I'm working with an example [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series/5048863#5048863) .

```
public class essaijfree2 extends ApplicationFrame {

private static final String TITLE = "Dynamic Series";
private static final String START = "Start";
private static final String STOP = "Stop";
private static final float MINMAX = 100;
private static final int COUNT = 2 * 60;
private static final int FAST = 100;
private static final int SLOW = FAST * 5;
private static final Random random = new Random();
private Timer timer;

public essaijfree2(final String title) {
    super(title);
    final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset =
        new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, COUNT, new Second());
    dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2011));
    dataset.addSeries(gaussianData(), 0, "Gaussian data");
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    XYDifferenceRenderer r = new XYDifferenceRenderer(Color.green,Color.red, true);
    xyPlot.setRenderer(r);



    final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    combo.addItem("Fast");
    combo.addItem("Slow");
    combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if ("Fast".equals(combo.getSelectedItem())) {
                timer.setDelay(FAST);
            } else {
                timer.setDelay(SLOW);
            }
        }
    });

    this.add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    btnPanel.add(combo);
    this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    timer = new Timer(FAST, new ActionListener() {

        float[] newData = new float[1];

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newData[0] = randomValue();
            dataset.advanceTime();
            dataset.appendData(newData);
        }
    });
}

private float randomValue() {

    return (float) (random.nextGaussian() * MINMAX / 3);
}

private float[] gaussianData() {
    float[] a = new float[COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = randomValue();
    }
    return a;
}

private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
    final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart(
        TITLE, "hh:mm:ss", "milliVolts", dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
    ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
    domain.setAutoRange(true);

    ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
    range.setRange(-MINMAX, MINMAX);
    return result;
}

public void start() {
    timer.start();
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            essaijfree2 demo = new essaijfree2(TITLE);
            demo.pack();
            RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
            demo.setVisible(true);
            demo.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to do this with a `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` as you specify the number of data points to keep, in youre case `COUNT = 2* 60`.

You may be  able to use a `TimeSeriesCollection`

Comment: But `TimeSeriesCollection` doesn't let me display only last 10 seconds but it shows all the value displayed

Comment: Thats the problem, you want to add a scroll bar to show historic data to a `Series` limited to 120 records.  In this case you will affect performance as you add more data. I'd consider adding a second chart to show the historic data using a [`SamplingXYLineRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=72854#72854)

Comment: I will put a button on my panel when clicking I try to make another chart with all data appears on the place of the old chart. I hope this is possible